# An easier way to work with {% tags %} in Django/Jinja templates with Emacs?

Tags: emacs, django-templates, jinja2

I'm writing a lot of Django/Jinja templates in Emacs. I'm already using [nXhtml](http://ourcomments.org/Emacs/nXhtml/doc/nxhtml.html), which does an okay job of indenting.

I'm looking for something that:

1. Inserts closing `%}` when I type a `{%`, or lets me hit a key to insert a `{% ▊ %}` (where `▊` is the cursor)
2. Makes it easier to create `{% if %}`/`{% else %}`/`{% endif %}` blocks
3. Maybe auto-adds `{% endfoo %}` for any `{% foo %}` tags

Suggestions?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Install [yasnippet](http://code.google.com/p/yasnippet/) and add your snippets to the nxml-mode, like

```
#name : {% %}
# --
{% $0 %}

#name : {% for %}
# --
{% for $1 in $2 %}
   $0
{% endfor %}


#name : {% if %}
# --
{% if $0 %}
{% else %}
{% endif %}
```

Save them in files *%* , *%for* and *%if* respectively.

Then you just type % following by a tab and it will insert {% %} with a cursor between percent symbols. Similar type %if for `if` construct and %for for a loop.

Answer (score 4):

By 2018, many things had changed. I believe many Emacs user use [web-mode](http://web-mode.org/) now instead of nXhtml which is no longer being developed [since 2012](https://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/nXhtml).

Web-mode support auto pairing (e.g. , {% … %}). When you open any html template, you can set which engine you want to use (M-x web-mode-set-engine), or web-mode will detect the engine for you.

Now, you don't have to rely on yasnippet to do this